# Hosting selenium scraper on render with cron job

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver, render

I want to schedule a selenium scraper somewhere in the cloud and run it every day. I tried setting up a cron job on render, however I got stuck at the point where it needs a google chrome binary file.

I tried installing chrome during the build, but I am still getting a no chrome binary found at specified path error.
I have everything else ready (the script, the requirements, the chromedriver).

1. Does any of you have any such experience? Is it possible to have what I am trying to get?
2. Do you have any better solutions for this case?

Any advice is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can specify the location of chrome as the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chromium/selenium.webdriver.chromium.options.html?highlight=binary_location#selenium.webdriver.chromium.options.ChromiumOptions.binary_location) says:

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/usr/lib/chromium-or-chrome-stable-path"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Try installing a stable version manually.